# Trying to add Elements to List<String[,]> S = new List<String[,]>();

Tags: c#, string, collections

I am trying to add Elements to the following. Its not working. How can i do it ?

```
List<String[,]> S = new List<String[,]>();
```

To tell you why i am trying such a thing; 
i initially needed the following ::

```
        String[,] s = new String[60,2] ;
        s[0,0] = ".NET CLR LocksAndThreads";
        s[0,1] = "Contention Rate / sec";
        s[1,0] = "ASP.NET Applications";
        s[1,1] = "Requests Rejected";
        s[2,0] = "Memory";
        s[2,1] = "Available Mbytes";
        s[3,0] = "Process";
        s[3,1] = "Private Bytes";
        s[4,0] = "Network Interface";
        s[4,1] = "Bytes Received/sec";
```

But then i thought why not use List. So please tell me what i am doing wrong ..

Comment: "not working" is a completely useless piece of information when trying to troubleshoot something. Might want to rework your question.

Comment: For one, I don't see how you add the elements.

Answer (score 6):

You appear to want to convert a 2D string array to something more meaningful for your given data.

Looking at those values in your 2D array, and based on the fact that it's an X by 2 array, it probably makes more sense to use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> S = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { ".NET CLR LocksAndThreads", "Contention Rate / sec" }, 
    { "ASP.NET Applications", "Requests Rejected" }, 
    { "Memory", "Available Mbytes" }, 
    { "Process", "Private Bytes" }, 
    { "Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec" }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want to store pairs of strings. If the first string in each pair is unique (which I suspect it is) then a `Dictionary` will do this for you.

e.g.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "a", "x" },
        { "b", "y" },
    }
```

If the first string in each pair is **not** unique, then you can use a collection of `KeyValuePair`.

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "x"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "y"),
    }
```